# Restricting my output to over a certain value

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to print an output from a dataset regarding matches played in the championship. However, I want to restrict my output to teams that have on average scored more than two goals per game. I have put  "`> 2`" behind the print statement, `[np.mean]` and `["goals"]`, but all I get are errors.

this is the code:

```py
football_stats = df.groupby("team")["goals"].agg([np.mean])

print(football_stats)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
football_stats = df.groupby("team")["goals"].agg([np.mean])

football_stats = football_stats[football_stats.goals > 2] 

print(football_stats)
```

Comment: try this one:


football_stats = football_stats[football_stats['goals' ]> 2]

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?